# delete all text after found word java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to cut the tail of the string in some cases - I have done this with indexOf and substring, but it slowed my code(( I  have thought about regular expressions but this tails have only similar beginnings - this is not "stable" word
 For example I have such string

```
 aaaaa bbb cc (bb) (r-1hh)
```

and I need a result

```
  aaaaa bbb cc (bb)
```

but there also could be such string

```
aaaaa bbb cc (bb) (r3-34fff)
```

or

```
 aaaaa bbb cc (bb) [tagBB- na]
```

So, the question is - could I use regex to find an index of tail ?

The other question - is IndexOf or Substring uses regex in java?

Comment: indexOf is faster than regex. If you want an exact match why do you want a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to find regex match position:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("i.*t");
String s = "my input string";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("match begins at " + m.start()); // 3
    System.out.println("match ends at " + m.end()); // 11
} else {
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```

But you can remove trailing text this way:

```
String res = s.replaceFirst("^(.* input).*", "$1");
System.out.println("'" + res + "'");
```

Or use an exact match without escaping each special char this way:

```
String res = s.replaceFirst("^(.* " + Pattern.quote("^something$wierd^") + ").*", "$1");
System.out.println("'" + res + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may write a regex which contains anything but `)` and ends on `)`, so you avoid matching anything after the first `)`.

Comment: this is not my case - because some times I have a valid info in brackets. (see first sample with (bb)) but anyway could you provide a sample ?

Comment: "Sometimes" is not a good combination with regex, you have to be able to specify it absolutely to avoid any errors. Matching `aaaaa bbb cc (bb)` is fairly simple, but how do you decide whether you need the rest of the string or not?

Comment: I have wrote a decision alg. for this - this is a specific to project logic. But as I understood regex could not gave me anything like Index? Regex is good for search of constant strings. I am right?

Comment: Not completely, regex is good for searching strings which can be formulated using a nondeterministic finite automaton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use $ to match the end of the string and then find a common pattern for your tail. Is it always going to be an alphanumeric/dash/space character situated between [] or ()? Then that's your pattern.

Then just substring everything between the beginning of your initial string and the beginning of the substring you found using the pattern for the tail.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

**Can regex be used to find the index of the String?**

You can use a Pattern and Matcher to acheive this.
Just noticed someone else has commented this so I won't give an example.

**Do the String methods IndexOf or Substring use regex in Java?**

No, String in java uses Character parsing. You can see the Javadoc or source for more detail on this.
You can acheive this with Java fairly easily, this example may be similar to your existing implementation:

```
public String truncate(String str, String tail) {
  int lengthOfTail = tail.length();
  int indexOfTail = str.indexOf(tail);
  return str.substring(0, indexOfTail + lengthOfTail);
}
```

*(error handling omitted for clarity)*